# How to upload text file seperate by tabs in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having problems with uploading a text file into my database using phpMyAdmin. The text file is seperated by tabs and looks like this:

`Date (txt) Date    Year    Month   Week    Year-Month  Year (Week Corrected)   Year-Week   Day Year-Day    Fiscal Week Year-Fiscal Week    Weekday
20140101    1-1-2014    2014    01  01  2014-01 2014    2014-01 01  2014-01         3
20140102    2-1-2014    2014    01  01  2014-01 2014    2014-01 02  2014-02         4`
I tried using this methode:

On the `Import` tab, select your file and then under `Format of imported file`:

- Choose `CSV using LOAD DATA`
- Ensure that the `Fields ... by` options are all blank
- Leave `Lines terminated by` as `auto`
- Under Column names, specify the name of the column into which you want the data to be inserted - i.e. `my_column` above
- Click `Go`

But this methode  gives me the error message:

SQL-query:

LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/phpyvgvLA' INTO TABLE `DATA_CALENDAR` LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
MySQL meldt: Documentatie

1045 - Access denied for user 'id7132527_barefoot'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: Like I said in the post i tried that methode, and it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: [This might help you then?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99339/correct-lines-terminated-by-for-query)